# Naming a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm guessing this is basic, but again I'm struggling.

I want to create a data frame from a .csv therefore I'm doing the obvious:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

But in this case I want to give the data frame a meaningful name so in an IPython console I can do this:

```
my_dataframe_name = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

My problem is that within a script, my_dataframe_name  is a string defined elsewhere i.e.

```
some_variable = 'my_dataframe_name'
```

So (eventually...) my question is how can I create the dataframe and have it named using the string held in another variable?

Best Regards,

Ben

Comment: Short answer - you can't use *value* of variable to define *name* of other variable. Long answer: you are probably doing something wrong. How do you access it later?

Comment: Or rather: you can, but shouldn't. Keep data out of your variable names.

Comment: Have been offered a solution that works using exec. But duly noted that I should probably avoid this approach if I'm creating a group of functions as I am. Thanks for the prompt feedback.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `globals()` to create global variable

```
some_variable = 'my_dataframe_name'

globals()[some_variable] = pd.read_csv(file_path)

print(my_dataframe_name)
```

---

But I would rather keep it in dictionary

```
all_dfs = {}

some_variable = 'my_dataframe_name'

all_dfs[some_variable] = pd.read_csv(file_path)

print(all_dfs[some_variable])
```

Comment: It´s exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

one way to do it is to use the exec function:

```
exec('%s = pd.read_csv(file_path)' % some_variable)
```

I don't know if there is a better way to do it, but this should solve your problem